# I cannot visit my gists from computer while I can from my Android phone app

Tags: github, gist

If I visit my gists (Github) from my computer (no matter which computer and what kind of OS), the message is given from Github as below:

```
Whoops.

We seem to have missed the gist of that gist you were looking for.
```

But I can visit my gists from my Android phone app (official Github app). Why?

I send email to Github, but they didn't give any answer.
And I searched from Google but seems no person met the same problem.

Example link: 
https://gist.github.com/tomxue/5369077

And please check below screenshots: I made a public gist and cannot access it from the website. But I can visit from my Android phone Github app.
The gist link is https://gist.github.com/tomxue/5369077
Could you please also try to visit it and let me know the result?

**Further**:
If I log out from Github website, then I cannot visit (github.com/tomxue) or Gists profile page(gist.github.com/tomxue).
If I login with my account tomxue, then I can visit (github.com/tomxue) (**shown as below 3rd screenshot**) but still cannot visit Gists profile page(gist.github.com/tomxue).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Please check my main post above, an example link is provided.

Comment: Can you verify that you are logged in to GitHub on both your phone and your computer *with the same user account*? The only thing I can think of that is going wrong is that you are creating private gists under a different account and you cannot access those from the computer. Also, try creating a public gist on your phone (notice the checkbox on the top of the screen to make the gist public) and then access it from the computer.

Comment: @IvanZuzak Thank you for your advise! I took some screenshots of the gist accessing issue. Please check my main post. I am sure that I am visiting current account's gist but not available for me. Could you please also take a try to visit it and see whether you can visit it?

Comment: @TomXue There is something strange going on with your account. I cannot access your GitHub profile page (https://github.com/tomxue) or your Gists profile page(https://gist.github.com/tomxue). This is why you are having problems, I think. Have you changed your GitHub username?

Comment: @IvanZuzak Thank you for your reminder! I noticed that now. I can visit my Github profile page only after I login. In any case, I cannot visit my Gists profile page. Maybe I have to contact Github person again.

Comment: I don't use github, but a quick search shows [only one tom xue](https://github.com/search?q=tomxue&type=Users&ref=searchresults). That said, using "tomxue2" in your link doesn't work for me either.

Comment: That may be another user account I created some time but I forget to use...Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

GitHub person contacted me just now and the problem was solved. I think I might paste the original message from them: "We introduced some new measures to fight spam, and your account was incorrectly flagged as spammy. I've cleared that flag and your gists should be available now." So thank all of you! Hope this post is useful for others.

Comment: This just also happened to me. Github now shows a warning at the top (screenshot) http://i.imgur.com/C0nH5Yp.png